# Multiprocessing in Python creates single process

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an issue with multiprocessing in python, refer to my code below :

```
processArray = []
downtimeObj = []
for x in range(0,len(clientMaster)):
    downtimeObj.append(Downtime(clientMaster[x]))
    processArray.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=downtimeObj[x].live(),))
    for j in range(len(processArray)):
        processArray[j].start()
    for z in range(len(processArray)):
        processArray[z].join()
```

Here I have an array of processes "processArray" and an array of objects of class Downtime. In my client master, im trying to iterate through the number of clients I have and create an object for each client, thereby creating a process for each client.

The current code creates a single process and runs the live() function chronologically.

I wish for all clients to have separate processes and the object.live() function to run simultaneously.

Comment: Does your code has the right indentation? Because right now your `processArray` will always have a single `Process` item inside.

Comment: `join()` blocks code until process will end running - so using it in loop `for x` is wrong idea - after starting one process it will wait for it ends before it will run another process. You should run it outside loop. And I thing you should run `.start()` also outside `for x` loop

Comment: `process` needs function names without `()` so you should rather have `target=downtimeObj[x].live` without `()`. Using `()` you run this function in main thread and is use result from this function as target - like `result = downtimeObj[x].live()` and `Process(target=result)`

Comment: you should learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change indentation and first run loop which only creates all processes. Next loop which runs `.start()`. And finally loop which use `.join()`

And `Process()` (similar to `Thread()`) needs function's name without `()` so later it can use `()` to start in in new process.

```
target=downtimeObj[x].live
```

If you use with `()` then it runs `live()` in current process and send its result as argument for `Process()` like

```
result = downtimeObj[x].live()
Process(target=result)
```

You could also learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())` - it will be more readable.

```
processArray = []
downtimeObj = []

# --- loop ---

for item in clientMaster:
    obj = Downtime(item)
    downtimeObj.append(obj)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=obj.live)
    processArray.append(p)

# --- after loop ---

for p in processArray:
    p.start()

for p in processesArray:
    p.join()
```

---

OR you should at least `.join()` run outside first loop

```
processArray = []
downtimeObj = []

# --- loop ---

for item in clientMaster:
    obj = Downtime(item)
    downtimeObj.append(obj)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=obj.live)
    processArray.append(p)
    p.start()

# --- after loop ---

for p in processesArray:
    p.join()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to send arguments then use tuple ie. `(value1, value2)`

```
Process(target=obj.live, args=(value1, value2))
```

and will run `live(value1, value2)`

For single argument you also need tuple ie. `(value1,)`
It needs `,` inside `( )` to create tuple with single element.

```
Process(target=obj.live, args=(value1,))
```

and will run `live(value1)`

You can see it also in documentation [Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to use `Pool` to always runs only 5 processes and get all results

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# --- function for Process ---

def my_function(item, arg1, arg2):
    obj = Downtime(item)
    return obj.live(arg1, arg2)

# --- create arguments for all processes ---

arguments = []

for item in clientMaster:
    arguments.append( (item, value1, value2) )

# --- use Pool and wait for all results ---

with Pool(5) as p:
     results = p.starmap(my_function, arguments)

# --- display all results ---

print(results)
```

Comment: What if I need to pass an argument in the live function? can you please make an edit for the same?

Comment: I added it to answer.

Comment: I added also example with `Pool` and getting results

Comment: Would it be appropriate to use Process(target=obj.live, args=(value1,)) ?

Comment: you are right - it should be with `args=` because after named argument `target=` it needs other values with named arguments too. I corrected it in answer

Comment: Thank you for your help!